# Independent set check by checking in graph is a clique

Tags: python, graph-theory, clique, independent-set

I have a homework question for an algorithm class regarding transforming an s-clique into a s-independent set. Below is code and the function at the very bottom `independent_set_decision(H,s)` is what I need to finish. I am stumped.

```
def k_subsets(lst, k):
    if len(lst) < k:
        return []
    if len(lst) == k:
        return [lst]
    if k == 1:
        return [[i] for i in lst]
    return k_subsets(lst[1:],k) + map(lambda x: x + [lst[0]], k_subsets(lst[1:], k-1))

# Checks if the given list of nodes forms a clique in the given graph.
def is_clique(G, nodes):
    for pair in k_subsets(nodes, 2):
        if pair[1] not in G[pair[0]]:
            return False
    return True

# Determines if there is clique of size k or greater in the given graph.
def k_clique_decision(G, k):
    nodes = G.keys()
    for i in range(k, len(nodes) + 1):
        for subset in k_subsets(nodes, i):
            if is_clique(G, subset):
                return True
    return False

def make_link(G, node1, node2):
    if node1 not in G:
        G[node1] = {}
    (G[node1])[node2] = 1
    if node2 not in G:
        G[node2] = {}
    (G[node2])[node1] = 1
    return G

def break_link(G, node1, node2):
    if node1 not in G:
        print "error: breaking link in a non-existent node"
        return
    if node2 not in G:
        print "error: breaking link in a non-existent node"
        return
    if node2 not in G[node1]:
        print "error: breaking non-existent link"
        return
    if node1 not in G[node2]:
        print "error: breaking non-existent link"
        return
    del G[node1][node2]
    del G[node2][node1]
    return G

# This function should use the k_clique_decision function
# to solve the independent set decision problem
def independent_set_decision(H, s):
   #insert code here
    return True
```

Comment: I will add that if I just return k_clique_decision(H,s), these are the test cases that pass and fail:  '**`SUCCESS`**`: Test case input: {1:{}}, 1`  


**`SUCCESS`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1}, 2:{1:1}}, 1`  

**`FAILURE`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1}, 2:{1:1}}, 2.`

    Expected result: False

**`FAILURE`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1, 3:1}, 2:{1:1}, 3:{1:1}, 4:{}}, 3.`

    Expected result: True


**`SUCCESS`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1, 3:1}, 2:{1:1}, 3:{1:1}, 4:{}}, 4`  '

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the definitions of "independent set" and "clique":

- Independent set: A set of nodes where no two are adjacent
- Clique: A set of nodes where every pair is adjacent

By these definitions, a set of nodes is independent if in the complement of the graph, the set is a clique. What can you do with the complement of the graph and the `k_clique_decision` function to solve your problem, then?

Comment: So I need to create a new graph, the complement, and then run 'k_clique_decision' on it? And I do this by making a link between any node that doesn't have a link with another node?  Am i getting warmer? :)

Comment: i updated code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394164/creating-clique-graph-to-determine-independent-set  however i cannot seem to get the complement graph created right.  What is wrong with the code?