# Creating clique graph to determine independent set

Tags: python, graph-theory

Trying to transform an s-clique into a s-independent set. Below is code and the function at the very bottom 'independent_set_decision(H,s)' is what I am struggling with.  I understand that I need to create a complement of the graph and then check if that graph is a clique. However, the function I wrote isn't creating the graph as intended.  Anyone have any advice please on what's wrong with that code?

```
# Returns a list of all the subsets of a list of size k
def k_subsets(lst, k):
    if len(lst) < k:
        return []
    if len(lst) == k:
        return [lst]
    if k == 1:
        return [[i] for i in lst]
    return k_subsets(lst[1:],k) + map(lambda x: x + [lst[0]], k_subsets(lst[1:], k-1))

# Checks if the given list of nodes forms a clique in the given graph.
def is_clique(G, nodes):
    for pair in k_subsets(nodes, 2):
        if pair[1] not in G[pair[0]]:
            return False
    return True

# Determines if there is clique of size k or greater in the given graph.
def k_clique_decision(G, k):
    nodes = G.keys()
    for i in range(k, len(nodes) + 1):
        for subset in k_subsets(nodes, i):
            if is_clique(G, subset):
                return True
    return False

def make_link(G, node1, node2):
    if node1 not in G:
        G[node1] = {}
    (G[node1])[node2] = 1
    if node2 not in G:
        G[node2] = {}
    (G[node2])[node1] = 1
    return G

def break_link(G, node1, node2):
    if node1 not in G:
        print "error: breaking link in a non-existent node"
        return
    if node2 not in G:
        print "error: breaking link in a non-existent node"
        return
    if node2 not in G[node1]:
        print "error: breaking non-existent link"
        return
    if node1 not in G[node2]:
        print "error: breaking non-existent link"
        return
    del G[node1][node2]
    del G[node2][node1]
    return G

# This function should use the k_clique_decision function
# to solve the independent set decision problem
def independent_set_decision(H, s):
    nodes = H.keys()
    I = {}
    for node1 in nodes:
        for node2 in H[node1]:
            if (H[node1])[node2] != 1:
                make_link(I,node1,node2)

    return k_clique_decision(I, s)
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe what you expect to get and what happens instead?

Comment: here are some test cases:

----  
  **`FAILURE`**`: Test case input: {1:{}}, 1.`

    Expected result: True

**`FAILURE`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1}, 2:{1:1}}, 1.`

    Expected result: True


**`SUCCESS`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1}, 2:{1:1}}, 2`  

**`FAILURE`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1, 3:1}, 2:{1:1}, 3:{1:1}, 4:{}}, 3.`

    Expected result: True


**`SUCCESS`**`: Test case input: {1:{2:1, 3:1}, 2:{1:1}, 3:{1:1}, 4:{}}, 4`

Comment: perhaps when a node has no links, my code is checking to see if there is a connecting node in the if statement.  However if there is no 'node2' then this may not work

Comment: Please read [this essay](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if (H[node1])[node2] != 1:
```

Your graph representation doesn't represent missing links with a non-1 value. It represents that a link is missing by not including the relevant dict entries at all. Iterate over all nodes instead of just the ones that have links, and check whether `node2` is a key in `H[node1]`:

```
for node1 in H:
    for node2 in H:
        if node2 not in H[node1]:
            make_link(I, node1, node2)
```

Comment: Thanks but in the line preceding, I have a for loop that is looking for node2 in H[node1].  How can I check if there is a node2 before iterating? DO I check if the dictionary value is null or empty somehow?

Comment: @Andy: Answer expanded.